# Java download any page - including 404, error-message pages?

Tags: java, inputstream, urlconnection, bufferedinputstream

I've used URLconnection.connect and BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()) to download pages, but unfortunately it seems it is unable to download any 404 pages or any other error-message pages, instead it throws an exception. Is there a way to change this behavior and get the error message that is displayed in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The implementation of HttpURLConnection throws exception when any http status except 2xx series is returned.

You should use [Jakarta HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to be able to get access to input stream (and therefore download any content) when error status is returned.

Comment: If you correct this answer to discuss `getErrorStream()` I would like to remove my down vote, so please comment back to me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can just use the getErrorStream() method of the HttpURLConnection object.

This will return the input stream.

Some sites, like msnbc.msn.com, give off 404 error but then provide a working page via the error stream..... no idea why they do this.

Comment: good to know. I will apply this today in my unit test environment.